# How to extract a file to a specific place that has the dot character in the path using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, jar

I am reading path from a JSON file:

- $path = zoomdata\conf\**consul.conf.d**\f1.txt
- filename: f1.txt

I am using the following command:

```
jar xf jar1.jar "$path"
```

I am using PowerShell.

My JSON file:

```
{
    "name": "zipZoom",
    "extension": "jar",
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "unpack": "TRUE",
    "thirdparty_version": "",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "fileName": "edc-mssql.properties",
        "file_extraction_path": "zoomdata\\conf\\",
        "file_destination_path": "release\\installers\\11.3.5.x\\setupfiles\\botinsight\\zoomdata"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "query-engine.properties",
        "file_extraction_path": "zoomdata\\conf\\",
        "file_destination_path": "release\\installers\\11.3.5.x\\setupfiles\\botinsight\\zoomdata"
      },
      {
        "fileName": "consul.json",
        "file_extraction_path": "zoomdata\\conf\\consul.conf.d",
        "file_destination_path": "release\\installers\\11.3.5.x\\setupfiles\\botinsight\\zoomdata"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your JSON file, highlighting the line you want to read the path from.

Comment: added in description

Answer (score 0):

Enquote you path in back ticks:

```bsh
$fileName = "f1.txt"
$path = "zoomdata\conf\consul.conf.d\$fileName"
Start-Process jar -ArgumentList "xf jar1.jar `"$path`""
```